'Correct' way to notate an integral with variable bounds evaluated at a given value
I am modelling water-waves in a tank, where the $x$-coordinate is along the tank's width, $y$ is along its length and $z$ is in the vertical. The waves are driven by a wavemaker on the tank's front wall, at $y=R(t)$. The rest of the tank is fixed between $y=L_y$ and $x\in[0,L_x]$, the base is $z=0$ and the free-surface height is $z=h(x,y,t)$. So the water fills the region $$x \in [0,L_x], \enspace y \in [R(t),L_y], \enspace z \in [0,h(x,y,t)].$$ The velocity is $\mathbf{u}(x,y,z,t)$, and by the no-slip boundary condition the velocity along the wavemaker is $\mathbf{u}(x,R(t),z,t)=\dot{R}(t)\hat{\mathbf{y}}$.
I'm modelling the system with Lagrangian mechanics, which involves writing integrals and including constraints such as BCs via Lagrange multipliers. Essentially, I need to integrate the expression $$\boldsymbol{\chi}\cdot\left(\textbf{u} - \dot{R}\hat{\mathbf{y}}\right)$$ over the whole surface of the wavemaker; that is, over the 2D surface given by the $xz$-plane evaulated at $y=R(t)$. $\boldsymbol{\chi}(x,y,z,t)$ is the Lagrange multiplier applying the constraint.
First, I need to integrate with respect to $z$, since its bounds depend on $x,y$. I then evaluate this integral at $y=R$ and integrate with respect to $x$. Would the following be the correct notation for the evaluation of the $z$-integral at a specific value of $y$:
$$\left.\left\{\int\limits_0^h\boldsymbol{\chi}\cdot\left(\textbf{u} - \dot{R}\hat{\mathbf{y}}\right)\,{\rm d}z\right\}\right|_{y=R}$$

You could just write the integral with each $x$ as some $x_0.$ i don't think there is one "correct" way, just stylistic choice.

Why not $$\int\limits_0^{f (a)}g(a,y),{\rm d}y,?$$

Ahh, good point, I forgot to mention in the question that I've actually dropped the brackets because the integrals are a bit more complicated than this example, and they're repeated often, so the reader would be well aware that (for example) $f$ is a function of $x$. So it's more like $$\left.\left{\int\limits_0^{f}g,{\rm d}y\right}\right|_{x=a}$$

That does not make sense. Where is the slot into which I am supposed to insert $x$ or $a,?$ If your integrals are more complicated than this example and you want advice about the notation we need to see those beasts.

No notation will help when we don't know what we are doing. What is $\boldsymbol{\chi},?$ As far as I can tell you want to integrate a function of $x,y,z$ over the three-dimensional region $x\in[0,L_x],y\in[R(t),L_y],z\in[0,h(x,y,t)],.$ (You mentioned very confusingly the "surface of the wavemaker".) I believe you want a volume. Why not write the integral as
$$
\int_0^{L_x}\int_{R(t)}^{L_y}\int_0^{h(x,y,t)} \dots ,dz,dy,dx\quad ?
$$

$\boldsymbol{\chi}$ is the Lagrange multiplier I mentioned in the question. It is a vector function of $(x,y,z,t)$. I don't want to integrate over the 3D domain, I want to integrate over the 2D domain defined in the $xz$-plane at $y=R(t)$

This sounds like you want
$$
\int_0^{L_x}\int_0^{h(x,R(t),t)}\left{ \boldsymbol{\chi}\cdot\left(\textbf{u} - \dot{R}\hat{\mathbf{y}}\right)\right}\Bigg|{y=R(t)} ,dz,dx,
$$
or (same but more clumsy)
$$
\int_0^{L_x}\left{\int_0^{h(x,y,t)}\boldsymbol{\chi}\cdot\left(\textbf{u} - \dot{R}\hat{\mathbf{y}}\right) ,dz,dx\right}\Bigg|{y=R(t)},.
$$
Somewhere you should mention that the integrand is a scalar function of $(x,y,z,t),.$ Putting that into notation will make the formula only more ugly.
